# Sharepoint online Site Permission

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I created a publishing site in sharepoint online and provided unique permissions. Two users (one internal & other external) provided full permissions. Internal user can access site but external user can't access site. Can anyone please assist what is the problem ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved now. The problem was that there was limitation of external domains in site collection feature.  If want to limit external sharing of site, follow below steps:

1- Got to  https://portal.office.com and click on Admins.

2- Click on Sharepoint in Admin Centers.

3- Click "More features" in left side.

4- Click "Open" on "Classic site collection page" in right side.

5- Select the site collection of the site and click on Sharing.

6- Go to Site Collection additional settings and add gmail.com (if there is already domain added, put space between two domains).

7- Click save button.

Now access the site using external user account.